# Flask API works correctly locally but returns 415 on Azure App Service

Tags: python, api, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-postgresql

#### Current environment

- Python 3.10
- Flask 2.3.2 and waitress 2.1.2
- Postgresql DB on Azure Postgresql managed service (flexible server)
- App Service running docker container for the server with same requirements as above
- Calling endpoints from python using `requests`

#### Code and use case

Relevant code for the server:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from waitress import serve
from paste.translogger import TransLogger

# --- Routes definition --- #
@app.route(f"{API_ENDPOINT_PREFIX}/hello", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    logging.info("Hello")
    return jsonify({"message": "Hello!"})


@app.route(f"{API_ENDPOINT_PREFIX}/filter/<tablename>", methods=["GET"])
def get_filter_options(tablename: str):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    logging.debug(f"Request data: {request_data}")

    # Doing stuff here and obtaining a variable options

    logging.info(f"Retrieved {len(options)} filter options for table '{tablename}'")
    return jsonify({"filters": options})


# --- Main --- #
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info(f"Welcome to Flask server")
    serve(
        TransLogger(app, setup_console_handler=False),
        host=API_ENDPOINT_HOST,
        port=API_ENDPOINT_PORT,
    )
```

`API_ENDPOINT_PREFIX` is set to `/api`.

Note that `/api/hello` is an endpoint for testing purposes, while `/api/filter/<tablename>` is supposed to be a working api to retrieve possible options for filter fields and return them to an ui. This api connects to the postgresql database hosted on Azure.

I launched this locally on `localhost:8000` and all works as expected. I also deployed the same to Azure App Service, and what happens is the the `/api/hello` endpoint still works fine, while the `/api/filter/<tablename>` returns **415**.

In both cases the api is called using the following snippet of code:

```
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}

requests.get(
        f"{BASE_API_URL}/filter/tablename",
        data=json.dumps({"filters": {}}),
        headers=header,
    )
```

where `BASE_API_URL` is alternatively `http://localhost:8000/api` when running locally or `http://app-service-name.azurewebsites.net/api` when running on app service.

#### What I've checked

General suggestions say to include the `Content-Type` and `Accept` header, which I do in any case. I also checked the connection between app service and hosted db, supposing that some problem may arise if the two services cannot communicate. TO this end, I created a Service Connector on the app service whose target is the hosted db, so I suppose everything is ok.

What seems strange to me is that the `/api/hello` endpoint, which does not require any payload, works fine in both environments, while the `api/filter/<tablename>` endpoint, which requires a payload, works differently.

Am I missing something? Which other actions can I take to further investigate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was simply that Azure App Service exposes the APIs through `https` instead of `http`. Just putting `https` in each URL solved the issue.